# _local management in symfony 4

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I try to set the variable {_local} in my routes ...here is the controller

```
    /*
    * @Route("/{_locale}" , name="home" , requirements={"_locale": "en|fr"})
    */
    public function generalHome($_locale)
    {
      dump($_locale) ;

      return $this->render('customer/home/home.html.twig');
    }
```

and when I type the url `/en`  in my browser,

Symfony returns the error :

```
No route found for "GET /en"
```

PS: I didn't modify any other file

Comment: Can you share more details? Would it work if you call another route with a static path in the same controller?

Comment: yes it's possible but imagine you with 10 nationalities to manage there will be a huge part of the code that will be redundant. And as you know so well we have to avoid duplicating code unnecessarily   . so your solution isn't as good as you think it is.

Comment: "Would it work" points to the possibility that you have another problem in your code. Just try it for debugging reasons, you may remove that method directly when it works

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but that looks like your route is not found. That could be caused by your routes.yml not importing Annotations:

```
# config/routes/annotations.yaml
controllers:
    resource: '../../src/Controller/'
    type: annotation
```

More Info on [Routing](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html)